# How to call remote resources via jQuery in excel web add-in

Tags: jquery, excel, add-in

I tried to do some simple exercises, the new dev platform is great.

But I encountered some problems when I want to call remote resources via jquery in a simple excel web add-in. Can you give me some guidance?

The code is simple, but it never works for me,

```
function getdata() {
  var url = "http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products";
  $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    Excel.run(function (ctx) {
      var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
      sheet.getRange("A1").values = data;
      return ctx.sync();
    });
  }).fail(function(xhr,status,error){
    Excel.run(function (ctx) {
      var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
      sheet.getRange("A1").values = xhr.responseJSON;
      return ctx.sync();
    }).catch(errorHandler);
  });
}
```

Thank you very much

I have added this domain in the manifest file

> ```
>  <AppDomains>
>     <AppDomain>http://services.odata.org</AppDomain>
>  </AppDomains>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem: The target url must use https.